# Swift: Find lowest score of player in players array and return player only if score is unique

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a property called score on a Player struct. I'm trying to find a way to filter through an array of players to find the lowest score. But the condition is that it should return the player only if it has a unique low score(score can't match another player). Else if two or more players do have the same low score return an array of all the lowest score players.
Below is a sample of the code:

```
struct Player {
    var score: Int
}

let players = [Player(score: 4), Player(score: 7), Player(score: 5), Player(score: 3), Player(score: 3), Player(score: 8), Player(score: 3)]
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This function gives you an array of `Player` with the lowest score :

```swift
func getLowestScorePlayers(for players: [Player]) -> [Player] {
    let minScore = players.map { $0.score }.min()
    return players.filter { $0.score == minScore }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct Player {
    var score: Int
}

let players = [Player(score: 4), Player(score: 7), Player(score: 5), Player(score: 9), Player(score: 3), Player(score: 8), Player(score: 3)]

func playerWithLowestScore(players: [Player]) -> Player? {
    // sort
    let sortedPlayers = players.sorted() { $0.score < $1.score }

    // filter by lowest score
    let filtered = sortedPlayers.filter() { $0.score == sortedPlayers[0].score }

    return filtered.count == 1 ? filtered[0] : nil
}


let solePlayerWithLowestScore = playerWithLowestScore(players: players)

if let player = solePlayerWithLowestScore {
    print(player)
} else {
    print("No single player with a low score.")
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you Mox! I will probably go with Nicolas's answer as that gives me the flexibility to show all low score players or just the sole low score by checking if the returned array is > 1.